# Добавить в корзину без перезагрузки страницы

Tags: php, ajax

Код функции:

```
function TDMPerocessAddToCart($arALLPRICES, $arPARTS) {
    if (isset($_POST["PHID"]) && strlen($_POST["PHID"]) == 32) {
        foreach ($arALLPRICES as $PKEY => $arPrcs) {
            foreach ($arPrcs as $arPrice) {
                if (!($arPrice["PHID"] == $_POST["PHID"])) {
                    continue;
                }
                global $TDMCore;
                $arPart = $arPARTS[$arPrice["BKEY"] . $arPrice["AKEY"]];
                unset($arPrice["INFO"]);
                unset($arPrice["EDIT_LINK"]);
                if ($arPrice["ALT_NAME"] == "") {
                    $arPrice["NAME"] = $arPart["NAME"];
                }
                else {
                    $arPrice["NAME"] = $arPrice["ALT_NAME"];
                }
                unset($arPrice["ALT_NAME"]);
                $arPrice["IMG_SRC"] = $arPart["IMG_SRC"];
                $arPrice["ADD_URL"] = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
                $arPrice["DETAIL_URL"] = $arPrice["ADD_URL"];
                $arPrice["DATE_FORMATED"] = date("j.n.y", $arPrice["DATE"]);
                $arPrice["CPID"] = substr(filter_var($arPrice["PHID"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT), 0, 9);
                $arPrice["TYPE_NAME"] = $TDMCore->arPriceType[$arPrice["TYPE"]];
                if ($arPrice["STOCK"] != "") {
                    $arPrice["SUPPLIER_STOCK"] = $arPrice["SUPPLIER"] . " (" . $arPrice["STOCK"] . ")";
                }
                else {
                    $arPrice["SUPPLIER_STOCK"] = $arPrice["SUPPLIER"];
                }
                foreach ($arPrice["OPTIONS"] as $OpName => $OpValue) {
                    if ($OpName != "VIEW" && strpos($OpName, "_") <= 0) {
                        if ($OpValue == "" || $OpValue == "0") {
                            unset($arPrice["OPTIONS"][$OpName]);
                            continue;
                        }
                        $arPrice["OPTIONS_NAMES"][$OpName] = Lng("PRICE_OPTION_" . $OpName, 1, 0);
                        continue;
                    }
                    unset($arPrice["OPTIONS"][$OpName]);
                }
                define("TDM_ADD_TO_CART", true);
                global $arCartPrice;
                $arCartPrice = $arPrice;
                return $arPrice["PHID"];
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

как реализовать через ajax?

Клиентская:

```
<?foreach($arResult['PRICES'] as $arPrice) foreach($arPrice as $key=>$value) {?>

        <?if(in_array($_REQUEST['article'],$value)) echo '<b>В наличии:</b> '.$value['AVAILABLE']."</br>"?>
        <?if(in_array($_REQUEST['article'],$value)) echo '<b>Доставка:</b> '.$value['DAY']." дней</br>"?>

        <?if(in_array($_REQUEST['article'],$value)) if($arResult['ADDED_PHID']!=$arPrice['PHID']) {?>
            <a href="/index.php?route=checkout/simplecheckout" class="btn btn-success" title="Оформить заказ"><?=$value['PRICE_FORMATED']?> <?=TDM_CUR_LABEL?> - Оформить</a>
          <?}else{?>
            <a href="javascript:void(0)" OnClick="TDMAddToCart('<?=$value['PHID']?>')" title="<?=Lng('Add_to_cart',1,0)?>"><?=$value['PRICE_FORMATED']?> <?=TDM_CUR_LABEL?> - Купить</a>
        <?}?>
<?}?>
```

При нажатии товар кладется в корзину и страница перезагружается.

Сам ничего не пробовал, так как не могу сообразить с чего начать

Comment: тут серверная сторона. А где клиентская? Что вы пробовали?

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы что то делать без перезагрузки то конечно AJAX.
А больше никак вы не проработаете тот или инной код на сервере

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю автору стоит через Ajax делать фоновый запрос на http(php) по другому не выйде. (сервер и клиент на двух разных машинах)

(кодом помочь не могу, js не знаю, может советом)